# getting data in the same row knowing the element value in the other column(both column name known)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

```
import pandas as pd
import random
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
print(data)
        Country   City
0       German    Berlin  
1       France    Paris

random_country = random.choice(data['Country'])
```

How do I get the corresponding city name in a quick way please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the country name retrieved to search the dataframe again it would be more efficient to extract the city at the same time. This can be achieved with the [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method

```py
random_entry = df.sample(1)
random_country = random_entry['Country']
random_city = random_entry['City']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
idx = random.choice(data.index)
random_country = df.loc[idx,'Country']
random_city = df.loc[idx,'City']
```

Comment: ggordon answered it a bit earlier than you. Appreciate your answer as well. Thanks.